# Should security question answers be hashed?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5

I'm working to a security system for a web application - admin section. If one admin want to make some important changes in application he will need to a answer to a security question.

My question is: the answer to this question should be hashed in database?

Also, I'm thinking to give to the administrators posibility to change their question/answer but admin could do this just if he confirm his identity using password. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Why not just have them enter their password in again?

Comment: Be sure to use proper hashing techniques. First, make sure you're using a random salt (also called a nonce) when hashing. Second, make sure you're using a hash algorithm that is not considered broken. This means no MD5, no SHA-1, and definitely nothing older. Some hashes to consider are SHA-256/512, bcrypt/EksBlowfish (same thing) and Whirlpool. Happy hashing!

Comment: @Jared I think is better to avoid using password too often

Comment: do people still use security question? Why not just send reset password link to their email?

Comment: @Dereleased I'm using Cakephp framework, I will use cake hash method

Comment: @Nishant is for admin section, for specific actions: edit, delete, etc

Comment: @morandi3 - Not sure what the thinking behind too often is.

Comment: the problem with secret questions is that they invariably are things you tell someone on a first date. A secondary PIN would be better.

Comment: @horatio So you're saying when you have a disastrous first date with the cute admin in the cubicle across from yours, there's more than just awkwardness in the office at stake? :)

Comment: :) absolutely. If someone on the street polled you about your favorite color and the first car you ever drove, you probably might not find such information to be potentially damaging, but they are 2 of the "secret questions" my bank forces me to pick from. I like to answer with something completely irrelevant to the question, but that's just me purple monkey dishwasher.

Comment: @horatio, right, but if you think about it, say the first car I ever drove was a 1991 ford f150, what part are you going to take out? ford? f150? f-150? 1991? And if the system only allows 3 tries before it locks you out, what is the real chance of them hacking it? Not to mention they need your current password for the system. That also assumes that they are actively "stalking" you in some form or another. A PIN number would be just as bad. I mean who really does not use their "phone number" or dob for the pin, aside from me? The better scenario is having them write their own question/answer.

Comment: Correct, it certainly depends on the implementation. For my bank: they might ask this on the phone, in which case a partial hit is the same as a full one. For a three strikes and you are out rule, I have a pretty good chance for your f150, but for my cat jiggles, I am nearly guaranteed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashing it is a great idea, in my opinion. As no one really needs to know it other then the original user, so better to keep that more of a "Secret" from just prying eyes.

As far as the ability to change it, that is a great idea as well, and requiring him/her to enter their password to change it is another good security approach.

I think you are on the right track with your thinking.

Comment: I'm thinking also to use strtolower before hash/check?!

Comment: Yea, see ceejayoz response, its a good practice for the security questions as most people never remember the exact case the used for it etc.

Comment: Add trimming and collapse all whitespaces as well. There is no point in hashing a password and leaving "security question and answer" to be easily digested.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, but be sure to normalize it before hashing - lowercase it, consider removing all characters that aren't alphanumeric, etc. If I enter "ceejayoz" as my question, it should probably accept " CEEJAYOZ " as well.

Comment: +1 for the normalizing. I generally do this on my own, but great advice to do it programatically!

Comment: I always sweat a little when asked a security question and I think, "Did I put elementary/state/last name on that?"

Comment: @ceejayoz is it enough to use strtolower() for normalizing ?

Comment: Depends on the question. I'd throw `trim()` in there too, at the very least. If you're asking for mother's last name, those two would probably be enough. If you're asking for street names, you might want to remove common things like "Rd.", "Rd", "Road" etc. so they don't have to remember which variant they used.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm thinking to give to the admins posibility to edit their question, but this is a bit "dangerous" because they can add then silly and easy questions?!

Comment: @morandi3, that is where educating your administrators comes into play. You could also set requirements for the answer. IE, needs to be at least 8 characters long and includes a space as part of a phrase like 'dog bully' or something similar. It all depends on how you want to set it up and what the minimum standards should be.

Comment: Sure, they can add silly/easy questions, but the flipside is that the more restrictive you are the more likely they'll decide to just write it down somewhere. I have to save my bank's security question answers on paper because most of the available questions are unanswerable for me - I don't have a single favourite author or musician!

Comment: Along with what ceejayoz said, it could also be very annoying to someone. Especially if changing settings occurs frequently. Depending on the system, you could have a system like on `SO`, where 2 people have to confirm a change instead of the `question` being typed in. Or keep the `question` valid for 5-10 minutes after it being entered and time it out after that time, so they are not constantly asked for it, which could be annoying, again depending on the system and the needs.