# Why don't the answers to "security questions" need to be stored securely?

Tags: security, passwords

I've done some work at a few places now where passwords are salted and hashed in the database, but the answers to the security questions are stored in plain text. Just now, I signed up for the online portal for my hydro company, and in the account management section, the security question and answer are displayed to me.

Given that security questions and answers often allow a user access to an account in a workaround way, without requiring the password, why are they allowed to be stored in plain text? Especially since people often have a limited pool of security questions to choose from, so they likely use the same answers across many sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with security questions is that they are by design completely insecure. The reason that they are stored in plain text is that they occasionally need to be looked at by humans and used by humans to verify that an answer is correct. If a user’s answer to their favorite food is “popped corn”, and they answer “popcorn”, that’s a valid answer.

Hashing the answers to security questions would require that the user know their previous answer *exactly*, just as if it were a password, and we already know that the user forgets their password (in those cases where the user is the one trying to access the account). The point of security questions is that they are real things that can be remembered and don’t have to be treated by the user as passwords.

Similarly, because these are not arbitrary answers in the way that passwords are, they are sometimes, as you noticed, displayed back to the user. This is so that they can change the answer when it is no longer correct. A password is an arbitrary response, but security question answers are not arbitrary. People’s favorites and even what or who they think inspired them can change over time. A user who is asked their favorite movie might choose the one they saw last night, and completely forget a year later that they ever rated it so highly.

For that matter, hashing the answers to security questions is of limited utility (mainly to security geeks who know to answer them randomly). Their very nature is that they are public. Hashing the model of the user’s latest car doesn’t keep the hacker from just reading their Facebook feed.

**The secure answer to security questions is not to use them.** Technically, they should be treated exactly like passwords, because for all practical purposes they *are* passwords. But if we hashed the answers to security questions, required users to choose strong answers, and didn’t allow them to use easily-guessable answers, then there would be no point to them.

Remember, the purpose of security questions and answers is to *bypass not knowing the password*. The more they’re treated like passwords, the more useless they become for that purpose.

Comment: Indeed, security questions are bad practice.  Research has shown that hackers do better at recovering users passwords than the original user, who often forgets his own answers.  NIST recently [advised against](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/) using secret questions for account recovery.  As an example, see the yahoo incident where hackers recovered yahoo's database including plaintext answers to secret questions.  Following incident, yahoo phased out secret questions for account recovery.

Answer (score 1):

There's no answer to "Why don't the answers need to be stored securely?", because they should.

A password is actually an answer to a security question too ("What is your password?"), so you [should always hash answers to security questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5747176/2298902) too as it's a way to authorize a user.